# Dynamic variable not working in php

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

I cant declare a dynamic variable. Hardcoded variable is working.
So basically I have a code that reads a .mdb file. Its working when the values are hardcoded but when make the values dynamic it doesnt work. Using double and single quote is working when defining in the variable even without quotes. My working code is

```
$userid = "91";
$sensorid = "1";
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("ADODB Oops!");
$conn->Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\standard\Att2003.mdb");
$data = $conn->Execute("SELECT * FROM Checkinout WHERE userid = '".$userid."' AND Sensorid = '".$sensorid."' ORDER BY CheckTime DESC");
```

It doenst work if I declare it as
    $userid = $userdetails['fingerprintid'];

I can assure that im getting the right value when using the 
    $userdetails['fingerprintid'];

This is the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message
>   '**Source:** Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC
>   Drivers
> **Description:** [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access
>   Driver] Not a valid bookmark.' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pages\attendance.php:21 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pages\attendance.php(21): com->Execute('SELECT * FROM
>   C...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\reception.php(51):
>   include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pages\attendance.php on line 21

Will update my question later as it think the problem is not with the syntax but rather with the database.
Im getting the error for the particular user but trying with other user using $userid = $userdetails['fingerprintid'] is working.

Comment: can you `var_dump($userdetails['fingerprintid']);` I suspect it's value might not be what you expect..

Comment: hey thanks for the reply the result is     string(2) "89" I only want the 89. how can i get it? but when i just echo $userdetails['fingerprintid'] it only return 89.

Comment: Did you cjeck your variable? there is no such thing as static/dynamic vars... they are variables hence ' dynamic'

Comment: What i mean is if i hardcode the number 89 its working but if i get it as $userdetails['fingerprintid'] which will be dynamic coz it will get the per user fingerprintid. Also used this $userdetails['id'] when using in a function and its working for me but not this time.

Comment: if `echo $userdetails['fingerprintid']` output is 91 **at the point in the code** where you have `$userid = "91";` then it is not possible to get other result with `$userid = "91";` or `$userid = $userdetails['fingerprintid'];`

Comment: sorry for the confusion since i said its dynamic, 91 is my hardcoded value and 89 is the new value im trying to get. I dont understand so you mean $userid = "91" and $userid = $userdetails['fingerprintid'] outputs the same thing? well yeah it does but i dont understand why its not executing. maybe is there any syntax error in my execute command?

Comment: ... ???
What I meant is... does not matter if it's hardcoded or not, hte answer will be the same.
I don't know if there is an error in the code. All I know is that saying `$a['b'] = 89; $c = $a['b']`  and `$c = 89` are exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, I also use this syntax in all my code and its working I just dont get it why its not working this time.

Answer (score 0):

Your IDs seem to be numeric, so try:

```
$data = $conn->Execute("SELECT * FROM Checkinout WHERE userid = ".$userid." AND Sensorid = ".$sensorid." ORDER BY CheckTime DESC");
```

Comment: Still error. Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b>Source:</b> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers<br/><b>Description:</b> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\pages\attendance2.php:22 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\pages\attendance2.php(22): com->Execute('SELECT * FROM C...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\reception.php(51): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pages\attendance2.php on line 22

Comment: just out of curiosity i tried to use $userid =  $_GET['fingerprintid'] and its working.